# Date subtraction formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field, date, fields

I Want to display a value using formula field such it is a time ahead of created date and Recordactive text field based on status field values to **Totaldays** text field.

If **Status=active** means **Today()-(record created date - Recordactive)**

here today()=6/10/2017, created date= 5/10/2017, Recordactive=25

now using date values: 6-(5-25)=-14

finally how can i show Total days value **-14** to **14** in **Totaldays** text field using formula field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Active'),
    TEXT(ABS(TODAY() - (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - RecordActive__c))),
    ''
)
```

Finally ABS is absolute value (ignoring the sign).

More info:

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=0#date_and_time_functinons
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm

Comment: But, Based on my Question How to show Totalvalue 14 using formula field

Comment: ABS should leave you with a number and then TEXT would be a safe way to convert it to text value (if your formula is really a text type, not numeric). Does it throw you any errors when compiling the formula?

Comment: As stupid as it is, such formula saves OK for me on Account: `IF(Phone = '',
    TEXT(ABS(TODAY() - (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - 25))),
    ''
)`

Comment: The formula field looks like not working. Its giving different value which is equal to `Recordactive`. But, it should return 14.

Comment: @eyescream are you getting the exact answer?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you guys, it's a decent implementation of the logic Sfdcprog asked about in his question. For records created today you'll of course have TODAY() = CreatedDate, they'll cancel each other out and your formula simplifies to just RecordActive's value. Tomorrow it should change. Etc. If the formula gives bad results experiment with it a bit, but still - same functions like the ones I've used will be in final solution, maybe just with different +/- signs or parentheses... You know best what business logic you want :)